# Cannot receive data submitted using curl in post method using php

Tags: php, curl

I been trying to pass data using post and curl in php and this is the code that will receive the data

```
<?php
# required headers
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

# include database and object files
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

use \Database\Db as Db;
use \Objects\Leads as Leads;

# get database connection
$database = new Db();
$database->Connect(
  getenv('DB_CONNECTION'),
  getenv('DB_DATABASE'),
  getenv('DB_USERNAME'),
  getenv('DB_PASSWORD'),
  getenv('DB_HOST')
);

# prepare product object
$leads = new Leads($database);

# get id of product to be edited
$fp = fopen('php://input', 'r');
$data = stream_get_contents($fp);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($rawData);
echo "</pre>";
```

and this is the code that send data

```
    $param = [
      'id'         => $result['id'],
      'transfered' => true
    ];

    $param = json_encode($param);
    $r = self::postSubmit($this->url . 'store.php', $param);
    dump($r);
```

and the functions code

```
  public function postSubmit($url, $param)
  {
    $ch = curl_init( $url );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $param);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    return curl_exec($ch);
  }
```

but when i try to run the code to see the result

the result just `""`
and in the database nothing has changed

Am i doing wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's not the main reason, but also a problem for sure:

```
$param = json_encode($param);
```

Either remove that line from code OR change it to

```
$param = http_build_query($param);
```

because CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS don't supports json - it supports urlencoded string or plain array. I would recommend just plain array - no need to bother with type conversion.